# Как обновить переменную сессии битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Ребята необходима помощь с вопросом сессии. Собственно стоит сам битрикс и Аспро: next. Реализовал простейший вариант выбора города с использованием сессии. Есть поле с названием города:

```
<div class="city_selector">Город: <?=$city;?></div>
```

Находится это поле в header.php. Для вывода информации в данное поле я использую следующий код:

```
<?php
$city = 'Не выбран';
if(isset($_SESSION['city'])){
    $city = strip_tags($_SESSION['city']);
}
```

Так же есть форма выбора города, которая находится в footer.php и выглядит примерно вот так:

```
<ul class="city-list">
   <li class="city-list-item">
       <a class="city-list-item-link" data-name="МОСКВА" href="javascript://">МОСКВА</a> 
   </li>
   <li class="city-list-item">
       <a class="city-list-item-link" data-name="ЧЕЛЯБИНСК" href="javascript://">ЧЕЛЯБИНСК</a</li>
   <li class="city-list-item">
       <a class="city-list-item-link" data-name="ОМСК" href="javascript://">ОМСК</a> 
   </li>
  ....
</ul>
```

Для выбора и изменения города я использую следующий код:

```
        $('.city-list-item-link').click(function(){
            var city = $(this).html();
            //Здесь сразу подставляю значение в другое поле в footer.php
            $('.selected-city').html(city);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/ajax.php',
                data: {
                    'method': 'city',
                    'city': city
                },
                success: function(data){
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
```

Ну и сам файл ajax.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$city = $_POST['city'];
$_SESSION['city'] = $city;
```

А проблема заключается вот в чем. Если зайти в административную панель (и быть авторизованным под администратором). То при выборе города все отлично работает, в переменную сессии добавляется город и при обновлении страницы этот город остается. Но если не авторизовываться на сайте (входить в группу "все пользователи") выбор города работает не корректно, например, после выбора города я обновляю страницу или перехожу на другую, город остается тем, что был до этого, а вот если я повторно перезагружу страницу, город поменяется на новый, то есть, чтобы город изменился мне необходимо дважды обновить страницу, хотя если авторизоваться под админом, город меняется сразу. Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: А ты не забываешь, что в аяксе надо ещё и перерисовать HTML содержимое city_selector, а не только поместить в сессию или куку значение. Не получается ли у тебя так, что HTML часть у тебя закеширована... В целом у меня всегда есть кусок, что перерисовывает текущий DOM элемент. window.location.reload(); это супер, но вот city_selector не факт что обновиться сам, всё крайне зависит от реализации. Админ и пользователь по разному могут кэшироваться.

Comment: Да, скорее всего вы правы на счет кэширования, поэтому так и происходит. Буду разбираться) Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: я по аяксу обновляю DOM, опять же люди проверяют куку. То есть ты пишешь не сессию, а куку и если кука есть - одно, куки нет - другое. Сессию не всегда разумно использовать.